# Mysql search with Match Against for searching relevant words

Tags: mysql, search

Is it possible to search for a term with its relevants using Mysql's MATCH AGAINST?

For example could I get **informational** by searching for **information**? I know it is possible with LIKE with % sign but unfortunately LIKE cannot calculate relevancy.

What is the best way of ordering results by relevancy and same time be able to searching for relevant words?

Comment: If you want to do any kind of advanced text indexing/searching stuff, you should really go with a specialized solution *(maybe solr, for instance)*, and not rely on MySQL's fulltext.

Comment: Is it PHP based or should apply to Apache, Pascal? Can I use it on a shared server?

Comment: It is a distinct, separate, software.

Comment: I see, it would be much to me for now. But will think about it for future. Thanks for advice,

Comment: @AmhetKemal : relevancy scores usually imply text found in a context. Finding the word 'cat' with 'hospital' most likely implies something about veteranarians, while finding 'cat' with 'night-club', implies something completely different ;-). A search engine keeps track of how close such words are near to each other (and what document they were found in), and so can **then** calculate a relevancy score. Solr is more advanced version of Lucene search engine, but I'm just learning about that, so I can't really tell you which is more appropriate for your need. Good luck!

Comment: @AmhetKemal: 2 other things. 1. When you're talking about searching with information%, in a search engine this is called stemming. The words are scanned and reduced to their stemmed versions-> informat% is likely the stem to all of those info* words (depending on search engine). 2. You might also find this discussion and the comment from GWW helpful in understanding word searching/stemming.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413909/php-search-word-degeneration-for-mysql-keyword-matching . I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for contribution shellter. I ll look for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in [this blog post](http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2006/05/mysql-fulltext-search-versus-lucene.html), [MySQL fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) is slow when it comes to ordering. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) would be an alternative.

Relevancy can be taken into account too. Here is the full list of [Lucene features](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html):

> Scalable, High-Performance Indexing
>
> - over 95GB/hour on modern hardware
> - small RAM requirements -- only 1MB heap
> - incremental indexing as fast as batch indexing
> - index size roughly 20-30% the size of text indexed
>
> Powerful, Accurate and Efficient Search Algorithms
>
> - ranked searching -- best results returned first
> - many powerful query types: phrase queries, wildcard queries, proximity queries, range queries and more
> - fielded searching (e.g., title, author, contents)
> - date-range searching
> - sorting by any field
> - multiple-index searching with merged results
> - allows simultaneous update and searching
>
> Cross-Platform Solution
>
> - Available as Open Source software under the Apache License which lets you use Lucene in both commercial and Open Source programs
> - 100%-pure Java
> - Implementations in other programming languages available that are index-compatible

Comment: Thanks Alp. I am  not sure about can it be used on shared hostings but it seems that is the best solution for now cause there is no other answers here. Also my hosting provider might think about installing it.